# Python Slicing List

Tags: python, list, 2d, slice

I have a 2d List

```
a= [['Turn', 'the', 'light', 'out', 'now'], ['Now', ',', 'I', 'll', 'take', 'you', 'by', 'the', 'hand'], ['Hand', 'you', 'anoth', 'drink'], ['Drink', 'it', 'if', 'you', 'can'], ['Can', 'you', 'spend', 'a', 'littl', 'time'], ['Time', 'is', 'slip', 'away'], ['Away', 'from', 'us', ',', 'stay'], ['Stay', 'with', 'me', 'I', 'can', 'make'], ['Make', 'you', 'glad', 'you', 'came']]
```

Is there an easy way to get a range of values from this list?

if I write:

```
print a[0][0]
```

I get 'Turn', but is there a way to slice multiple things out of the list and make a new list? If I have a value i=0 and n=2 I am looking to make a new list that starts at a=[i][n] and makes a new list with the list items on either side of that index.

Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry, can you make an example of the output you want? if it is simple slicing it is pretty obvious...

Comment: Related: [The Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
print a[0][0:2]
```

or

```
print [d[0] for d in a]
```